# How to have Packery fire after LazySizes loads images

Tags: javascript, html, responsive-design, lazy-loading, packery

I am using [lazysizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes) to lazy load my images but also am trying to use [Packery](http://packery.metafizzy.co/) and I can't figure out how to have the Packery script fire after lazysizes loads all my pictures as it won't lay out the pictures right. This is the code I have

```
<script>
// initialize Packery
var $container = $('#container');
// init
$container.packery({
itemSelector: '.item', percentPosition: true,
}); 
</script>
```

I want it to fire after lazysizes adds the class 'lazyloaded' to img class, since it replaces lazyload with lazyloaded.

```
<div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-purple">
            <a href="#image-1"> <img data-sizes="auto" data-srcset="Photos/kirby-thumb.jpeg 350w, Photos/kirby-thumb-med.jpeg 500w, Photos/kirby-thumb-lrg.jpeg 750w" data-src="Photos/kirby-thumb.jpeg" class='responsive-img lazyload' id="thumbnail">
          </div>
          <div class="card-content blue-grey">
            <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Kirby</span>

          </div>
          </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unstested but in case I get your question right, it should work like this. You test if the amount (`array.length`) of the lazyload class (I used the default class) is the same as the 'loaded' class. You put this test in a timeout loop, so the script runs every X milliseconds to check if the condition is fulfilled. As soon as the amount is the same - you kill the timeout loop and trigger packery.

```
// simple test - in case your orginial selector is lazyload
// the amount of lazyload and lazyloaded has to be the same.

function testAllLoaded() {
    return ($('.lazyload').length === $('.lazyloaded').length);
}

var testDelay = 10; // timeout in milliseconds 


$().ready(function() {
    // ask until test is fullfilled...
    var $container = $('#container');
    var fire = setTimeout(function() {
        // all loaded
        if(testAllLoaded()) {
            // run packery
            $container.packery({
                itemSelector: '.item', percentPosition: true,
            });
            // kill timer
            clearTimeout(fire);
        }
    } , testDelay );

});
```

Comment: It didn't work but I think the reason why is `var $container = $('#container');` is missing. I tried to add it before $container.packery but then it "deactivated" that function.

Comment: @OwenDunnigan the answer was pseudo code, for sure you need to be sure to do this on document.ready and required libs / dependencies are loaded. I have updated my answer and what do you mean with 'deactivated'?

Comment: Well in my editor when I put the `var $container = blah blah blah`, the `$container.packery{...});` isn't highlighted in blue anymore. If I copy just that part of the function and execute it in the console in chrome, packery activates and it works fine.

Comment: That is so weird, anyways thank you so much for helping!

Comment: @OwenDunnigan http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ywgmxb Demonstrates the script is running.

Comment: [With Var](http://i.imgur.com/HwCjxnJ.png)
[Without Var](http://i.imgur.com/ld9BgCp.png)
Here is what I am talking about when I add the var line of code and how it deactivates the `$container.packery`

Comment: @OwenDunnigan well - so what? Code is working, see the codepen in the comment before, whatever your editor did with the syntax highlighting.